# What adhesive is best to glue strain gauges to metal?

Tags: strain-gage, gauge, glue, adhesives

I'm trying to use [these](https://www.omega.com/pptst/SGD_LINEAR1-AXIS.html) strain gauges to measure bending of a metallic cantilever (metal TBD). Does anyone know what adhesive I can use to glue the strain gauges? I'd rather not have to use an oven for curation, unless it is my very last resort.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you done any research on this question yourself? It's a pretty broad question right now, and asking for the "best" is usually a matter of opinion. Please tell us what you have considered and what your particular application is.

Comment: IMO special glue for strain gauges, that you can't buy on supermarket or on aliexpress.

Comment: Ask the Omega guys – they are the experts in their strain gauges, and will definitely know best.

Comment: the link that you provided has adhesive for sale https://www.omega.com/pptst/Strain_Gage_Adhesives.html

Answer (score 2):

I have experience with two-component HBM X60 glue specially made for strain gauges. It's quite expensive, but i can tell, it withstands a lot.

But in general, i would say that any kind of fast cyanoacrylic glue would suit your needs. I have tried 350 ohm, one axis strain gauges with cheap cyanoacrylic glues which you can get on every corner, and it worked well.